# how to guess file encoding

Tags: pandas, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a file (an author list from the Library of Congress) with lines like:

```
Arteaga, Ana Mar�ia
Corval�an-V�asquez, Oscar E.
```

(when printed to linux console)

I'd like to read those (either  into a pandas dataframe or a set of lines)

```
  df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\t', header='infer', lineterminator=None,encoding='latin1') #lineterminator \r\n hits error
```

or

```
with open(fname,'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as fp: 
    lines=fp.readlines()
```

but both are not quite right , giving me output like

Arteaga, Ana Marâia

(again when printed to console) 
when I am pretty sure the actual name here should be María.

Does someone recognize this format?

Comment: What does the source you got the bytes from say the character encoding is? Can you got back and ask (or listen, as in, for the Content-Type HTTP response header)?

Comment: The names should probably read *Arteaga, Ana María* and *Corvalán Vásquez, Oscar E.*. So wherever the replacement character (question mark in black diamond) appears, it's next to a character that should be accented. It could be an indication that the original file is UTF-8. Use a *hexdump* tool to check if the accented characters require one byte (ISO-8559-1) or two bytes (UTF-8). Note that the encoding mismatch could also be due to your console. It needs to be configured for the correct encoding as well.

Comment: The original file has 0xE269 at the âi of Marâi.  If considered as one  byte/char then you indeed get âi,  while if you look for E269 as a two-byte codepoint it points to a private user area, which I dont imagine is what was intended.   I see a "Josâe" in this file as well, again the 0xE2 coming before the e , so it seems like the 0xE2 is being used to indicate an accented version of the character to come. Does that sound like a known format to someone?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to be the '[marc-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARC-8)' format .

```
yaz-iconv -f marc8 -t utf8 infile.txt  > outfile.txt
```

took care of the conversion to utf8 , with the sole hiccup being that yaz killed all the line terminators (both for \r\n and \n versions of the file).

Those can be returned with something along the lines of

```
sed 's/\[/\n\[/g' outfile.txt > outfile_utf.txt
```

(for example in my case where each line starts with a '[' character)